# Update beans (I18N) for a Spring MVC Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, spring, internationalization, javabeans

I've a webservice written with Spring MVC for a webapp.
The user could change the locale and so the language of his page, so a call to my webservice is done with this information. For information, at startup, I load few beans for my webapp configuration. These beans attributes needs to be internationalize

My question is how can I update the values of my bean directly from a user call ?

Comment: I would love to understand what you want but I am afraid I don't. What I understand, you have Spring MVC application and you want to give user an ability to change his/her language on demand. However, I am completely missing the point - what Beans attributes you want to internationalize? And what it has to do with loading (or injecting in fact) these Beans?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I'm sorry about that...Indeed, I've a Spring MVC webservice which provides configuration for a webapp. The user could change the locale on his webapp, and so a new call to my webservice is made. The configuration is set in my beans, and thats the data I sent back to the user. In this way, I need to get my bean internationalize... But after few search, I think I missing the point, and I'm going to consider doing the trick with Freemarker or velocity and their templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here:

One is overall i18n architecture. At best Beans (controllers, models) should not contain any translatable texts, therefore no i18n work would need to be done to make them localizable. This is ideal situation which doesn't happen to often in practice.

Another is a way to make Controllers localizable. Again, there are two possible approaches: one is to use resource keys instead of strings, messages, etc. and resolve it in your View to real translation, just before displaying it to user, another is to make Controllers read these messages from resources - you said that you know Locale, so it could be done. If you are going with latter solution, you probably need to limit your Scope to request (as different users might want to use different languages and as far as I understand what you wrote users might want to change their language on the fly).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm goind to change my conception in my webservice, and try to adapt for I18N. Thanks